# EF code generation template: spot the difference?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-generation

I made an EF project (DB first) some time ago, using the legacy ObjectContext template.  This generates everything into one massive honkin' file.  There are a few downsides to this, like if I ever want to view the file, the IDE takes a while to load it all into memory, and modifications take a while to refresh.  Plus it makes things difficult to see at a glance in source control history: if I want to know what changed, I have to do a file diff between two versions of one enormous file, rather than simply seeing the changes in isolated files, generated as one per class.

So I decided to try tinkering with creating a code template that will generate the **identical** code, only with one file per class.  And I thought I had done well, because the code compiles fine... but when I open the app, I get an error:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>
> The property for the relationship 'AssessmentSchool' contains a Role 'Assessment' has a type 'SchoolManagement.BL.Assessment' that is not valid for a relationship End. Change the End Role to an EntityType.
>
> The property for the relationship 'AssessmentSchool' contains a Role 'School' has a type 'SchoolManagement.BL.School' that is not valid for a relationship End. Change the End Role to an EntityType.

And it proceeds to list every many-to-many intersection table in the system (twice; one for each end of the relationship).  In the case of `AssessmentSchool`, the table simply has a `AssessmentID` and a `SchoolID`.

So I compared the declaration of the relationship in the old `MyContext.designer.cs`, finding any place where the relationship is mentioned, and compared to the new code.  Can you spot the difference?

**OLD data context:**

```
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("SchoolManagement.BL", "AssessmentSchool", "Assessment", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(SchoolManagement.BL.Assessment), "School", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(SchoolManagement.BL.School))]
```

**NEW data context:**

```
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("SchoolManagement.BL", "AssessmentSchool", "Assessment", RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(SchoolManagement.BL.Assessment), "School", RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(SchoolManagement.BL.School), false)]
```

(Yes, there are small differences: the new file has a `using System.Data.Metadata.Edm` statement at the top of the file, and the `false` for the `isForeignKey` parameter is anyhow the default value.  And I tried manually deleting that parameter and it didn't make a difference.)

**OLD Assessment class:**

```
[XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
[SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
[EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("SchoolManagement.BL", "AssessmentSchool", "School")]
public EntityCollection<School> Schools
{
    get
    {
        return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<School>("SchoolManagement.BL.AssessmentSchool", "School");
    }
    set
    {
        if ((value != null))
        {
            ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<School>("SchoolManagement.BL.AssessmentSchool", "School", value);
        }
    }
}
```

**NEW Assessment class:**

```
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("SchoolManagement.BL", "AssessmentSchool", "School")]
    public virtual EntityCollection<School> Schools
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<School>("SchoolManagement.BL.AssessmentSchool", "School");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<School>("SchoolManagement.BL.AssessmentSchool", "School", value);
            }
        }
    }
```

The symmetrical relationship is also in the `Class` class, but I won't bother listing it here.

This code looks pretty identical to me, and it compiles fine, but it just throws the runtime error above.  Obviously there's another trick somewhere that I'm missing.  But what?

Comment: The code you posted appears to be identical. My guess is that the differences lie another place. My recommendation would be to manually break apart the monolithic generated code, see if it works and compare each and every file then. My guess is that the relationships are getting messed up somewhere it isn't obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I was generating the `EntityObject` classes without their decorators:

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="SchoolManagement.BL", Name="Assessment")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class Assessment : EntityObject
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Accept your own answer so the question properly gets filtered. Glad you solved it!